# Datadog monitor using terraform

Tags: terraform, datadog

Currently we have only one monitor that aggregates errors across all the API calls. I want to split and have monitor per API.

I am trying to understand if I can create datadog monitors (alert on error count) for all the end-points in a service without having to implement resource for each end-point. Is there a way datadog can gather this information based on the APIs and construct monitor dynamically?

Answer (score 1):

In case you send the api as a tag together with the metric then you can define the monitor as "Multi Alert" for each tag value.
The the monitor will trigger for each api separately and of course you can use the tag inside the alert title and message.

https://docs.datadoghq.com/monitors/create/types/metric/?tab=threshold